# How to get id in the URL by submitting form

Tags: php

Hi Everyone, I have a code in which i have 3 forms which are
interrelated with each other and they are POST. So my question is that
when i submit a form want to send id in the URL so later on when i
submit another form i can get that id from the URL... Hope you guys
understand actually what i want.

```
<form action="index.php?kid=<?php echo $kid; ?>" method="POST">
   <fieldset style="padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px; padding-top:0px; ">
        <legend><span class="urdu20">خرچہ سیکشن</span></legend>
        <p class="abc"> 
              <input class="toAdd" type="text" name="karaya" id="karaya" size="17" />
              <label for="karaya"><span class="urdu20">کرایہ:</span></label>

        </p>
        <p class="abc"> 
              <input class="toAdd" type="text" name="custom" id="custom" size="17" />
              <label for="custom"><span class="urdu20">کسٹم:</span></label>

        </p>

        <p class="abc"> 
              <input class="toAdd" type="text" name="store-fees" id="store-fees" size="12" />
              <label for="store-fees"><span class="urdu20">سٹور فیس:</span></label>

        </p>
        <p class="abc"> 
              <input class="toAdd" type="text" name="market-fees" id="market-fees" size="10" />
              <label for="market-fees"><span class="urdu20">مارکیٹ فیس:</span></label>

        </p>
        <p class="abc" > 
              <select class="toAdd" name="commision" id="commision" style="margin-right: 10px;">
                          <option value="7">--- 7% ---</option>
                          <option value="8">--- 8% ---</option>
                          <option value="9">--- 9% ---</option>      
              </select>

              <label for="commision" style="margin-right: 30px;"><span class="urdu20">کمیشن :</span></label>

        </p>
        <p class="abc"> 
              <input class="toAdd" type="text" name="mazdoori" id="mazdoori" size="15" />
              <label for="mazdoori"><span class="urdu20">مزدوری:</span></label>

        </p>
        <p class="abc"> 
              <input class="toAdd" type="text" name="wapsi-khracha" id="wapsi-khracha" size="11" />
              <label for="wapsi-khracha"><span class="urdu20">واپسی خرچہ:</span></label>

        </p>
        <p class="abc"> 
              <input class="toAdd" type="text" name="munshiyana" id="munshiyana" size="14" />
              <label for="munshiyana"><span class="urdu20">منشیانہ:</span></label>

        </p>
        <p class="abc"> 
              <input class="toAdd" type="text" name="daktar" id="daktar" size="16" />
              <label for="daktar"><span class="urdu20">ڈاکتار:</span></label>

        </p>
        <p class="abc"> 
              <input type="text" name="kham-bekri" id="kham-bekri" size="12" />
              <label for="kham-bekri"><span class="urdu20">خام بیکری:</span></label>

        </p>

        <p class="abc"> 
              <input type="text" name="jumla_kharch" id="jumla_kharch"  size="10" />
              <label for="jumla_kharch"><span class="urdu20">جملہ خرچ:</span></label>

        </p>

        <p class="abc">
              <input type="text" name="pukhta-bekri" id="pukhta-bekri" size="10" />
              <label for="pukhta-bekri"><span class="urdu20">پختہ بیکری:</span></label>

        </p>

        <p class="abc">
              <input type="submit" name="kharcha_btn" id="kharcha_btn" value="Save"/>
        </p>
  </fieldset>
```

Comment: You don't need to send the id in url- you can use the method 웃웃웃웃웃 posted in the answers :)

Comment: The problem is that m not getting id in the url by submitting a form

Comment: actually i want that id so then i can fetch it in the database

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
  <table>
     <tr>
         <td><input type="hidden" name="kid" value="<?php echo $kid;?>"</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

And in index.php

```
echo $_POST['kid'];
```

Or You can do it like what you did.

```
<form action="index.php?kid=<?php echo $kid; ?>" method="POST">
  <table>
     <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_GET['kid']))
        echo $_GET['kid'];
?>
```

Comment: @user3116035  Read about XSS(Cross-site scripting) [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass POST values in URL. You can pass it using get method in form or like this.

```
<a href="index.php?kid=<?php echo $kid; ?>">click</a>
```

Or if you want to send using post method.You can do like this:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="kid" />
</form>
```

and get value of *kid* in response like this:

> $_POST['kid'];

Answer (score 0):

Or try this to get parameter kid from the url

```
echo $_GET['kid']
```